# Create multiple column in summarize in pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

In R, I can summarize the data using more than one data columns as follows:

```
`library(dplyr)`
    df %>% 
        group_by(product_id) %>% 
        summarise(
          Total_count = n(),
          Avg_rating = mean(star_rating, na.rm = T),
          Total_product =  round((n() / dim(df)[1]) * 100 ,2) 
    )
```

But, I want to perform the same activity in pandas.

Comment: You should explain what that does for people who don't use R.

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` we have `agg`

```
df.groupby('product_id').agg({'product_id':'count','star_rating':'mean'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to add one more new column. How can i do?